# python xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy - how to specify local port range

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

Is there an easy way to specify the source port range the xml-rpc client connection should originate from?

Let's suppose there is a firewall between the client and xml-rpc server which passes traffic to the server only from specific sockets (defined by IP and port range).

By default the `xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy`  lets the OS to decide which local port to use. As a result each xml-rpc call opens connection to the server originating from its own socket which stays in TIME_WAIT state until the timeout expires. On windows `netstat -b` shows such connections:

```
C:\tmp>netstat -b | grep 51000
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1552         TIME_WAIT    0
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1562         TIME_WAIT    0
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1561         TIME_WAIT    0
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1553         TIME_WAIT    0
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1559         TIME_WAIT    0
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1558         TIME_WAIT    0
  TCP    ZIBI:51000             localhost:1557         TIME_WAIT    0
```

What I would like to achieve is a configurable range for ports (15XX from the example above) the `xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy` would use when calling rpc methods on the server.

Answer (score 2):

`:` is delimiter between host and port.

```
netstat -a | grep :15*
```

Comment: Thanks but the question is not about filtering netstat output; it's about configuring ServerProxy object so it uses configured local port range when communicating with an xml-rpc server. Probably a custom transport must be defined with an overridden socket.bind() function but I was hoping someone already implemented such option.

Answer (score 0):

After getting from ServerProxy call:

```
cli = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(..)
```

down to

```
<httplib.py>

class HTTPConnection:

  _http_vsn = 11
  _http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.1'

  response_class = HTTPResponse
  default_port = HTTP_PORT
  auto_open = 1
  debuglevel = 0
  strict = 0

  def __init__(self, host, port=None, strict=None,
             timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, source_address=None):
```

I found the source_address kw used to specify what I was looking for. Additional stack overflow search against source_address leads to thread: [Python: Is it possible to set the clientport with xmlrpclib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269849/python-is-it-possible-to-set-the-clientport-with-xmlrpclib) which defines the custom transport specifying source address and more-less answers my question; at least it's a good starting point to implement the port range.